# How do I import a png file in Postscript with Ghostscript?

Tags: filter, png, ghostscript, postscript

I'm trying to place a png image on a postscript document for conversion to a pdf file using Ghostscript (v 9.15) ps2pdf.  I've found that the following code works nicely with a jpg file, but I need to import png files instead.  It looks like i must need a different filter, but I can't find one that works. Does anyone have a solution?

```
239                     % number of pixels in the horizontal axis
67                      % number of pixels in the vertical axis
8                       % bits per color channel (1, 2, 4, or 8)
[239 0 0 -67 0 67]      % transform array... maps unit square to pixel [ w 0 0 -h 0 h ]
(My_Logo.jpg) (r) file  % see page 587 and page 77 for more details
/DCTDecode filter       % see page  589
false                   % pull channels from separate sources
3                       % 3 color channels (RGB)
colorimage              % see page 544 and page 288 for more detail
```

Answer (score 5):

PostScript doesn't support PNG directly, it does support JPEG which is why your code above works.

If you want to read image data from a PNG file you will need to open the file, strip the header, then read each chunk individually parsing the data from it. It might be easiest to write the bitmap data to an intermediate file, but its perfectly possible to write a stream decoder to supply the data as required for a procedural image data source.

Fortunately PostScript (level 3 for certain, most versions of level 2) does support Flate, so you don't have to write the decompression code in PostScript, you can use the filter directly.

You will need to specify a colour space, depending on whether the PNG uses a palette or not.

PostScript is a programming language, so this is all possible, it will take an experienced PostScript programmer a couple of days to write and debug it I should think.

NOTE! PostScript does not support transparency, so you cannot apply alpha channels from PNG files at all.

Comment: Bummer.  So the next best solution is to just convert the png file to a jpg file, and then import it like above, right?

Comment: JPEG is a lossy compression method, you're probably best exporting it as a raw bitmap or something equally suitably simple and using that.

Comment: PPM is a well-documented "raw" format that would work. It could make large files, though, since there's no compression at all. And you still need to strip the header.